# How to async between Mongodb and azure search

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Mongodb on azure (not Mongodb Atlas), I installed manually Mongodb on three VMs on Azure, what I'm looking for is, everytime a new record is inserted or updated or delete on Mongodb I want this change to be refletcted on Azure Search, do you have any idea How van I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in Azure Search Indexer for Mongo, one option is to migrate your existing Mongo DBs to Azure Cosmos with the Mongo API. See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-mongodb-cosmos-db-online).
Another option is to use the Azure Search push API, for which you need to watch for changes in the Mongo DB, see [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/changeStream/) and based on those newly added or deleted docs then use the Push API the make changes to the index, see this tutorial using the .NET Azure search sdk https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-optimize-indexing-push-api

Answer (score 0):

If you migrate your current MongoDB to [Azure Cosmos DB API for MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/mongodb-introduction) as suggested in this thread,  Azure Cognitive Search has a [Cosmos DB Mongo DB indexer in Public Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb-mongodb) and you can opt to have it enabled according to that documentation and give it a try.